# Displaying an HTML page on Android

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to display this HTML webpage on both iOS and Android:

```
<html>
<style>
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(63, 14, 109, 1);
}
.loader {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4em;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: .8em solid rgba(218, 219, 223, 1);
    border-left: .8em solid rgba(58, 166, 165, 1);
    animation: spin 1.1s infinite linear;
}
.loader, .loader:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -4.05em;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

</style
<body>
<div class="loading">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
</body
</html>
```

On iOS it looks fine, but on Android WebView it becomes a tiny purple bar surrounded by white background.

Comment: In what browser?  How are you displaying it?  Chrome, Firefox, Samsung browser, WebView?  There isn't just one browser on Android.

Comment: Yea when using Android WebView